# Using calc() with tables

Tags: css, html-table, fixed-width, css-calc

I'm trying to get a table with fixed-width `td`s and variable-width `td`s.

Im using the CSS `calc()` function, but somehow it seems like I can't use `%` in tables.

So that is what I have so far:

```
<table border="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="width:100%">
        <td style="width:30px;">1</td> <!--Fixed width-->
        <td style="width: calc( (100% - 230px) / 100 * 40);">Title</td> <!--Width should be 40% of the remaining space-->
        <td style="width: calc( (100% - 230px) / 100 * 40);">Interpret</td> <!--Width should be 40% of the remaining space-->
        <td style="width: calc( (100% - 230px) / 100 * 20);">Album</td> <!--Width should be 20% of the remaining space-->
        <td style="width:80px;">Year</td><!--Fixed width-->
        <td style="width:180px;">YouTube</td><!--Fixed width-->
    </tr>
</table>
```

How I see it, it should work, but it isn't.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Or maybe has an other suggestion how I could reach my goal?

Comment: I wouldn't use calc yet :) Wait at least 6 more months until the support for cal reaches every browser, this way you'll avoid lot's of compatibility issues. For different TD width's try to use <colgroup>. Have fun.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Tables have difficult rules about distributing the space of the columns because they distribute space dependent on the content of the cells by default. Calc (atm) just wont work with that.

What you can do however is to set the [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/table-layout) attribute for the `table` to force the child `td` elements to get the exact width you declared. For this to work you also need a `width` (`100%` works) on the table.

```
table{
   table-layout:fixed; /* this keeps your columns with at the defined width */
   width: 100%;        /* a width must be specified */

   display: table;     /* required for table-layout to be used 
                          (since this is the default value it is normally not necessary;
                          just included for completeness) */
}
```

and then use plain percentages on the remaining columns.

```
td.title, td.interpret{
    width:40%;
}
td.album{
    width:20%;
}
```

After using up the space for the fixed width columns, the remaining space is distributed between the columns with relative width.

For this to work you need the default display type `display: table` (as opposed to say, `display: block`). This however means you can no longer have a `height` (including `min-height` and `max-height`) for the table.

[See your modified Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6usWN/2/)

Comment: I really wish that it worked this way, but on at least current FF (35) and GC (40) it doesn't. Putting in the percentages squashes the width of the other cells to their minimum render width as if "auto" was set. Perhaps because my first row, where I am setting the widths, is a header row (th cells)??

Comment: @LawrenceDol let me see your example and we will figure it out together.

Comment: @Christoph: It seems like the crucial missing factor is that the table must have a `width` set; setting `width:100%` resolves my problem and causes the fixed layout to work as expected.

Comment: The other mistake I had made was setting the table to `display: block` to get it to respect a `min-height`. It must be `display: table` to have the `fixed` layout respected.

Comment: @LawrenceDol A table should never have another display type than `display:table`. If it does, there is something wrong and probably different markup (most likely plain divs) should be used. Also, nowadays the flex-box layout can be used to take care of a lot of things which "in the old days" were accomplished by table layouts. But thanks for the edit, the width indeed is an important factor!

Answer (score -2):

Calc is the general function.

`-webkit-calc` is for webkit.

Add those in according to the browser you're using.

Regardless, your -calc- function will be ignored. having 3 td's that will be 40% of the remaining width? Thats 120% in total. This is a table. The parent's width will always take precedence.

However, if you have the TD's in in 5%, it the total width will be smaller than that of the table, hence it will also be ignored.

Bottom line: don't use calc with table.

Comment: firefox dropped the prefix somehere with version 18 or so, chrome also dropped it some while ago. So you only need the `-webkit` prefix for safari. Opera does not support this at all.

Comment: ahh. I didnt know that. Regardless of the syntax though, his approach does not have a solution with calc.

Comment: incidentally the width of one column should be 20%, so it sums up to exactly 100% of remaining space, which in theory should work out fine. The problem just lies in the nature of tables distributing the space of the columns dependent on the content in the default table-layout setting.

Comment: technically, if each column is 20%, then you could just set 20% width. Why use calc at all right?

Comment: OP wants to have some colums with a fixed width and the rest of the columns shall occupy the remaining space in 4|4|2 distribution. That's why he is using calc to calculate the remaining space of the table.