# Why is my calc() failing when used in a table in all browsers except Chrome?

Tags: css, calc

I'm using `calc` to specify the width of a table's  cells. This works in Chrome, but no other browsers.

Caniuse doesn't mention any [issues relating to calc](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) in other browsers.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="first">One</th>
      <th class="second">Two</th>
      <th class="third">Three</th>
      <th class="fourth">Four</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="first"></td>
      <td class="second"></td>
      <td class="third"></td>
      <td class="fourth"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS (though I'm using Sass):

```
table {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

th:nth-child(2n) {
    background: grey;
}

th.first {
    width: calc(100% * 0.1);
}

th.second {
    width: calc(100% * 0.4);
}

th.third {
    width: calc(100% * 0.25);
}

th.fourth {
    width: calc(100% * 0.25);
}
```

As you can see, IE11 resolves all cells to the same width:

[image]

There is a CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/Pedr/pen/VYgPog).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Sass.  Unless this is a problem related to the Sass -> CSS compilation problem, only the compiled CSS should be provided.

Comment: ...and why use calc anyway since you're multiplying by 100%?

Comment: @Paulie_D This is a much simplified version. The 100% is just for ease of example.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you're talking about in IE11. It calculates the widths just fine for me.

Comment: @TylerH It calculates all widths as being 25% (see screenshot added to the question) which is not correct. Compare to Chrome for example where each cell has a width derived from its `calc` calculation.

Comment: @Pedr Seems Chrome is the only one who does it differently. Firefox, Safari, and IE11 all handle it the same way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873302/using-calc-with-tables It seems like it has to do with how table column widths are calculated http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.4 tl;dr You can't use `calc()` with tables.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks. It does seem to be the case that calc is non-functional when used in tables.