# Using calc() in table

Tags: css, css-calc

I am trying to use `calc` to fix the width of my `th:last-child` which differs from the others by 15px. What I've done is:

```css
th:last-child {
   width: calc( (100% - 30px)/12 + 30px );
}
table, tr {
width:100%;
border: 1px solid black;
height:10px;
}
th {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: calc( (100% - 30px)/12 );
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
    <th>Column 7</th>
    <th>Column 8</th>
    <th>Column 9</th>
    <th>Column 10</th>
    <th>Column 11</th>
    <th>Column 12</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td>Row 5</td>
    <td>Row 6</td>
    <td>Row 7</td>
    <td>Row 8</td>
    <td>Row 9</td>
    <td>Row 10</td>
    <td>Row 11</td>
    <td>Row 12</td>
 </tr>
  
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

[JS Fiddle reproduction](https://jsfiddle.net/maxi_mizer/58z6p9tk/4).

I've divided by 12 because it is the number of columns in my table. As I understood 100% is treated as the width of the parent. The problem is that finally, I don't get what I would expect, any idea why?

Comment: Share your markup please.

Comment: Can you provide a piece of html code where this css applies?

Comment: The width of a table cell is determined by the column in which it sits, if you need it to be wider then you'll need to use `colspan` on the given cell (if you want it to be narrower then you'll need to use `colspan` on the other cells in the same column).

Comment: I added my fiddle

Comment: what you are looking for is simple padding-left or padding-right I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set `table-layout` property to 'fixed'.

See [using calc() with tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873302/using-calc-with-tables)

And working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rpyydd5n/3/

Comment: instead of answering you should mark as duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're setting the `table` to a `width` of `100% + 15px`. So unless the parent element allows for that, most browsers will recalculate back to `100%` and scale the `TH`'s and `TD`'s accordingly. Why not use `min-width` on the last child?

Answer (score 0):

change this in css

```
th:last-child {
       width: calc( 100%/12 + 100px );
       background-color:#ccc;

 }
th{width:5%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a **padding-right of 15px on the last th** to expand it, then using **a div inside that th** with a tricky **width calc(100% + 15px)**, it doesn't give 1/12 of the table width + 15px, it gives instead the natural width of that ***last th*** content + 15px, which is not exactly what you are requiring.

The reason why I posted this right away is just to share an idea than can be useful to solve the problem:

```css
table, tr {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:10px;
}

th {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

th:last-child {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

th:last-child > div {
  width: calc(100% + 15px);
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
    <th>Column 7</th>
    <th>Column 8</th>
    <th>Column 9</th>
    <th>Column 10</th>
    <th>Column 11</th>
    <th>
      <div>Column 12</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```