# CSS calc not working for <td> width

Tags: html, css

I'd like **Cell A** to leave exactly 100px for the remain two cells.  I would think `calc(100% - 100px)` would be sufficient as this works just fine in many other situations.  Why isn't it working here?

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center
}

td+td {
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
}

td:first-child {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell A</td>
      <td>Cell B</td>
      <td>Cell C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637941/using-calc-in-table

Comment: @CasperSL - nope.  Setting `table-layout: fixed` (as per the accepted answer there) does not work.  I've updated the snippet here to demonstrate.

Comment: Read this one also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873302/using-calc-with-tables?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: yes, i read all of these questions before i posted.  I you look at my snippet you'll see all of the suggestions there are already present.  if you have an answer please post.

Comment: So is this supposed to work with a unknown number of columns? If you will know the number of columns, doing it in reverse by setting the last two columns to 50px wide each works.

Comment: @cjl750 - Thanks but that's not what I'm after.  I want to know why it doesn't work.  That is the question I am asking.  Also, setting two columns to 50px each is not the same as leaving 100px and letting them set their own width based on content which is something tables excel at.

Comment: No worries. I am curious about it too; never really tried to do something like this with a table before so never realized it was a problem. FWIW you can achieve the desired result with flexbox instead of a table. Probably have to dig into the spec to see what it says about `display: table-cell` to get to the why.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Chrome, it seems to work when defining the width on a [`colgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup) element:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center
}

td+td {
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
}

colgroup:first-child {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup/>
  <colgroup span="2" />
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell A</td>
      <td>Cell B</td>
      <td>Cell C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Update April 1st, 2020**

This no longer seems to work in the current version of Chrome. I'll leave the answer to serve as a test case should the behavior change in the future.

Comment: interesting - I do see it working in chrome, but not firefox.

Comment: Yeah, same here. Trying out a couple of alternatives, but no luck so far.

Answer (score -3):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center
}

td+td {
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
}

td:first-child{
  width: calc(100% / 6 * 3.5);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell A</td>
      <td>Cell B</td>
      <td>Cell C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```