# Equal-width td with one td being narrower

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and want all columns to be the same width (irrespective of content), except for the last one, which is supposed to be 20px narrower than the first two.

`td:nth-child(3) { width: calc(100% - 20px); }` breaks the layout unfortunately.

I am aware of similar questions ([CSS calc not working for <td> width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686914/css-calc-not-working-for-td-width)), but unfortunately, no working solution is given. Is this not possible with pure CS??

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td { border: 1px solid red; }

td:nth-child(1) { width: 100%; }
td:nth-child(2) { width: 100%; }
td:nth-child(3) { width: calc(100% - 20px); }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>l</td>
    <td>lol</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `max-content` for a single row:

*to apply the width of the widest td from the third column will require JavaScript.*

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;

}

td:nth-child(3) {
    width:max-content ;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>l</td>
    <td>lol</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>l</td>
    <td>lol</td>
    <td>333</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a JavaScript possible approach :

```js
var bigW = "0";
var myTable = document.querySelector("table#test");
myTable.style.width = "auto"; //remove width 

for (let td3 of document.querySelectorAll("td:last-of-type")) { // check width of last td in each row
  td3W = td3.offsetWidth; // get width
  if (td3W > bigW) { // is it the biggest value ?
    bigW = td3W;
  }
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--myW", bigW + "px"); // update css var()
  myTable.style.width = "100%"; //reset width
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td:last-of-type {
  width: var(--myW, 2em);/* if var not set, then use default value*/
}
```

```html
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <td>l</td>
    <td>lol</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>l</td>
    <td>lol</td>
    <td>32 12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>l</td>
    <td>lol</td>
    <td>3333333333</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>l</td>
    <td>lol</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```