# CSS - calc not working Firefox

Tags: html, css, calculated-columns, calc

I am trying to dynamically add the widths to `td` which works fine in Chrome and Safari but not in FF.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6usWN/29/)

**HTML**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Interpret</td>
        <td>Album</td>
        <td>Year</td>
        <td>YouTube</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    border:1px solid red;
}
td:first-child{
  width: calc(100% / 6 * 0.5);
}
td:last-child{
  width: calc(100% / 6 * 2);
}
```

If I hard code the pixel value instead of `100%` for eg., `calc(690px / 6 * 2)`, it works.

Comment: You will have better luck with flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line of CSS:

```
table {
    // table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

`table-layout: fixed` enables you to apply your own widths to a table. I have no idea why Firefox isn't coöperating with this given rule.

For reference: 
[using calc() with tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873302/using-calc-with-tables)

Comment: @Turnip Oh? I read it from the top voted answer in the reference thread. I'll adjust it. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed! But fixed layout provides equal width to all the `td` and it doesn't change when the size of the content varies.

Answer (score -1):

In order for this to work, as I understand it, while attempting to simulate a fixed cell width is to change the `table-layout` from `fixed` to `auto` as well as set a default width for all `td`'s.

To do this dynamically, we divide the table width by the number of columns (in this case as a percentage) -- `100 / 6 = 16.66666...`.

Then we use that value within the `calc()` for `:first-child` and `:last-child`, by replacing `100%` with `16.6666%` while also keeping the existing modifiers (`0.5` and `2`, respectively).

**CSS**

```
table{
    table-layout:auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{

    border:1px solid red;
    width: 16.6666%;
}
td:first-child{
  width: calc(16.6666% * 0.5);
}
td:last-child{
  width: calc(16.6666% * 2);
}
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px090zhx/1/)

Comment: You don't need to divide it manually, it will work when you change the `table-layout` to `auto`.

Comment: @aravindtrue in order for it to work in Firefox, as per OP's request, it was necessary to do it manually or else all the columns between first and last would be varying widths. Setting it explicitly fixed this issue by having those columns be fluid, yet uniform, while still allowing first and last to be explicit (by percentage * modifier).