# Adjust HTML table colum size both with percent and fixed sizes?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table with the following widths of columns.

Is it possible to use both percents and absoulte widths as shown in my graphic?

This is because some columns make no sense below a certain width and always need the same width and others are more flexible.

[image]

Comment: This post may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873302/using-calc-with-tables

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```css
#fixed{
    table-layout:fixed;
}
td{
    border:1px solid red;
}

td:nth-child(even){
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<table id="fixed" border="0"  style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50px;">1</td> <!--Fixed width-->
        <td style="width:50%">Title</td> 
        <td style="width:50%">Interpret</td> 
        <td style="width:20px">1</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: We should not use inline styles as much as possible it is not recommended.

Comment: @Ishtiaq it is *more to maintain*, when using a lot of HTML/code. In this example, the OP asked for one row of a table , hence I used inline css. It produces the exact same output.

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand, you can achieve this by applying `styles` with `table` i.e `table-layout: fixed;` and `width:100%;`. Also `width` of `td` using `px` and `%`. According to your design, you are using four columns and I wrote code for the four columns;
Following would be your CSS;

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 50px;
}

td:last-child {
  width: 20px;
}

.second-column {
  width: 50%;
}

.third-column {
  width: 50%;
}

td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: grey;
}

td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="second-column">2</td>
    <td class="third-column">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this is what you required.

Comment: You should use external CSS and should avoid to use inline styles

Comment: Thanks @m4n0 its better to use snippet.